# Getting asciidoc to generate slides with embedded latex

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am interested in generating slides using asciidoc markup. Thus far I have been able to generate some slides using asciidoc tool by passing the flag `-b slidy` to the asciidoc executable as given here: https://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/slidy.html#(3)

However, when I try to embed Latex expressions like `$\alpha + \beta$` it just gets rendered as is. I know there is a tool called [asciidoctor-latex](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-latex) which can be used for generating "normal" HTML pages / PDF files containing the Latex symbols 
but when I tried `-b slidy` flag with asciidoctor-latex I get the error

> ```
> asciidoctor: FAILED: missing converter for backend 'slidy'. Processing aborted. (RuntimeError)
>   Use --trace for backtrace
> ```

How should I go about installing the necessary slidy backend?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is a backend for slidy included in the asciidoc program (python) distribution, but currently there is no such backend for asciidoctor (the ruby implementation of AsciiDoc).

You can generate LaTeX with asciidoc (python) [LaTeX Backend](http://asciidoc.org/index.html#X1), but that probably won't help with embedding formulas in slidy. I guess it is easier to write a preprocessor script that replaces your LaTeX-Code with an svg-image (external reference to a file generated by eg. [dvisvgm](https://dvisvgm.de)).